# spring Kafka Ambiguous methods for payload type

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to consume two different type of payloads from Kafka topic using `spring-kafka-2.2.0` and `spring-boot-2.1.0` but unfortunately no luck so far blowing out with exception.

So I have two models in my project `com.kafka.model.Professor` and `com.kafka.model.Student` and i configured them in type mapping also. But I'm not sure which part I'm missing on this deserialization.

**Config**

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

@Value("${kafka.consumer.bootstrap-server}")
private String bootstrapServer;

@Bean("consumerConfigs")
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-4");
    props.put(JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS,
            "professor:com.kafka.model.Professor, student:com.kafka.model.Student");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "test-4");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "1");
    return props;
}

@Bean("consumerFactory")
public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
    JsonDeserializer<Object> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Object.class);
    jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(), jsonDeserializer);
}

@Bean("kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "KafkaAutoConfiguration")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.BATCH);
    return factory;
    }

}
```

**Listener class**

```
@Service
@KafkaListener(topics = "test-events",id = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory-11")
public class KafkaConsumerService {

@KafkaHandler
public void student(List<Student> stu) {
    System.out.println(stu);
}

@KafkaHandler
public void professor(List<Professor> pro) {
    System.out.println(pro);
   }


}
```

**Error**

```
2019-02-15 13:04:33.060 ERROR 14863 --- [actory-11-0-C-1] o.s.k.listener.BatchLoggingErrorHandler  : Error while processing:
ConsumerRecord(topic = stores-pricing-easytest-manual-events, partition = 4, offset = 1189400, CreateTime = 1550096019845, serialized key size = 7, serialized value size = 49, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = student, value = {studentName=thomas, rollNum=109, age=35})

 org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Ambiguous methods for payload type: class java.util.ArrayList: student and professor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@KafkaHandler` approach doesn't work with `BATCH` mode. At least in the way you have it now: there is just no method to handle a distinguished batch by the generic arument.

Consider to turn off a batch mode or just handle everything in a single `@KafkaListener` method which already accepts a `List` as an argument for payload with any generic information.

NOTE: Apache Kafka doesn't distribute deserialized record between different batches. They all are going to be produced for the listener in the same `ConsumerRecords`. So, your logic with attempt to distribute by the generic type in the list is never going to happen, even if we would figure out a generic type of the method argument... So, the plain `RECORD` more is your saver.

Comment: you mean if I remove the batch mode it should work with this config? I'm I right sir?

Comment: Yes, but your methods should accept already play types, not lists

Comment: sir it is working with the changes but also I getting error messages 
```Error while processing: ConsumerRecord
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: No method found for class java.util.LinkedHashMap``` any idea on this sir

Comment: sir then batch processing will not support multiple payloads from topic am I right?

Comment: Looks like that is some generic JSON you don't have mapping for. So, it is deserialized into a generic hash map structure. You can have a one more `@KafkaHandler` with a `isDefault  = true` option: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/#class-level-kafkalistener